# Order of evaluation if logical operator is missing

Tags: c

Following is the C program.

I excepted it to go in else but it goes in if.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int iAge = 10;
    int iMinAge = 1;
    int iMaxAge = 18;

    if(iMinAge >= iAge <= iMaxAge)
    {
        printf("\n in if...");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n in else...");
    }
}
```

what is the order of evaluation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iMinAge >= iAge <= iMaxAge
```

is equivalent to

```
(iMinAge >= iAge) <= iMaxAge
```

and thus

```
0 <= iMaxAge
```

So, it is evaluated as true.

Answer (score 2):

`if(iMinAge >= iAge <= iMaxAge)` this doesn't work in C (not in the way you intended anyway). 
if you want to test if `iAge` is in the range of [`iMinAge`, `imaxAge`]

it is done like this: `if ( iAge >= iMinAge && iAge <= iMaxAge)`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, relational operator associativity is from left to right.
Now,in the if loop

```
if(iMinAge >= iAge <= iMaxAge)
```

execution starts from left to right as per associativity, so first iMinAge>=iAge is evaluated, which returns 0,now

```
0<=iMaxAge
```

which is true(1), so statements inside if gets executed.